# Stepper motor ABCD versus A+A-B+B-

Tags: stepper-motor

I am replacing a stepper motor and am checking that the wiring is the same as my old motor.  All of the wires are colored the same: black, green, red, blue.  But my old motor uses the convention black A+, green A-, red B+, blue B- and includes this diagram.  [image: diagram]

My new motor includes a very similar diagram.  But with some added detail and labels: black A, red B, green C, blue D.

[image: detailed diagram]

Can I treat the wiring the same to my stepper driver?

Comment: Yes, the mapping you propose looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as you get the coil connections in the proper order everything should work.

Comment: Could you clarify what is meant by the proper order?  I am a little confused. I think you are saying make sure the two pairs match up on a given coil and that's all that matters

Comment: Correct As long as you get the proper pair of leads for each coil connected properly on the driver you're set.